# call variable outside function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't call the LinearLayout by the id directly so i put it in variable did work just fine
but right now i have two function using the same variable , i try put the variable like this but
my application keep crashing

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val indcon:LinearLayout =findViewById(R.id.indicatorsContainer)
    private  val  introSliderAdapter = IntroSliderAdapter(
    )
```

## Fun1 setupIndicators

```
 
private fun setupIndicators() {
        val indicators = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(introSliderAdapter.itemCount)
        val layoutParams: LinearLayout.LayoutParams =
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
        layoutParams.setMargins(8,0,8,0)
        for (i in indicators.indices) {
            indicators[i] = ImageView(applicationContext)
            indicators[i].apply {
                this?.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        applicationContext,
                        R.drawable.indcator_inactive
                    )
                )
                this?.layoutParams = layoutParams
            }
            indcon.addView(indicators[i])
        }
    }
```

## Fun2 setCurrentIndicater

```
   private fun setCurrentIndicater(index: Int) {
        val childCount = indcon.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val imageView = indcon[i] as ImageView
            if (i == index) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        applicationContext,
                        R.drawable.indcator_active
                    )
                )
            } else {
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    applicationContext,
                    R.drawable.indcator_inactive
                )

            }
        }
    }
```

**I declare the variable inside each function it worked fine but give me the different result**

full code

```
    
    private fun setupIndicators() {
        val indicators = arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(introSliderAdapter.itemCount)
        val indcon:LinearLayout =findViewById(R.id.indicatorsContainer)
        val layoutParams: LinearLayout.LayoutParams =
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
        layoutParams.setMargins(8,0,8,0)
        for (i in indicators.indices) {
            indicators[i] = ImageView(applicationContext)
            indicators[i].apply {
                this?.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        applicationContext,
                        R.drawable.indcator_inactive
                    )
                )
                this?.layoutParams = layoutParams
            }
            indcon.addView(indicators[i])
        }
    }
```

```
    private fun setCurrentIndicater(index: Int) {
        val indcon2:LinearLayout =findViewById(R.id.indicatorsContainer)
        val childCount = indcon2.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val imageView = indcon2[i] as ImageView
            if (i == index) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        applicationContext,
                        R.drawable.indcator_active
                    )
                )
            } else {
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    applicationContext,
                    R.drawable.indcator_inactive
                )
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only reference views when the layout file is setup which is in `onCreate()` method. Just declare the `indcon` variable globally like this:

```
private lateinit var indcon: LinearLayout
```

and then initialize it in `onCreate()` before calling both functions:

```
indcon = findViewById(R.id.indicatorsContainer)
```